# cant import numpy though its installed in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

I couldnt import numpy though I had it installed in the system

```
steven@steven-VirtualBox:~$ apt-cache policy python-numpy
python-numpy:
  Installed: 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 1:1.8.2-0ubuntu0.1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:1.8.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: How are you trying to import it? What error message do you get?

Comment: @MatteoItalia I am using python 2.7.10

Comment: @ChathanDriehuys well just open the python script from the terminal and import numpy

Python 2.7.10 (default, Nov 27 2015, 18:37:43) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: @Squart I just installed numpy using `apt-get install python-numpy` and didn't get the import error you did. My `apt-cache` looks identical to yours so I have no idea what's going on. Sorry.

Comment: Did you get `ImportError: No module named _numpy` or others?

Comment: @orvi yes that correct! ImportError: No module named numpy

Comment: what is the output of `which python` ?

Comment: @orvi /usr/local/bin/python

Answer (score 2):

From the comment I find that your local build of python is installed in /usr/local/bin and then does not have access to packages (like numpy) installed system-wide.

So try using:

```
/usr/bin/python -c "import numpy"
```